# How to update curl on windows using Cygwin?

Tags: curl, cygwin

I already have curl installed on my Windows. I am using apt-cyg in Cygwin to upgrade the curl. I run command "apt-cyg install curl". It downloads and start installing the latest version 7.59 but then after installation when I type curl -V it gives me the old version 7.40. what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use Cygwin setup to update curl.

The problem of using `apt-cyg` to update some cygwin packages is that you can not update the programs/libraries used by `apt-cyg` itself.

Comment: if that's the case, then why the f isn't apt-cyg throwing some error?